# R: Different results from intersect() and gIntersects() when checking if polygon intersects raster

Tags: r, raster, intersection, r-raster

Based on this post (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255025/r-raster-masking-a-raster-by-polygon-also-remove-cells-partially-covered) I set up the following rasters and one SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and then used `raster::intersect` and `rgeos::gIntersects` to check wether the rasters include the polygon:

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)

# create rasters and store them in a list
r1 <- raster(xmn=1, xmx=5, ymn=1, ymx=5, nrows=4, ncols=4)
r1[] <- 1:length(r1)
r2 <- raster(xmn=5, xmx=9, ymn=1, ymx=5, nrows=4, ncols=4)
r2[] <- 10:(length(r2)+9)
r3 <- raster(xmn=1, xmx=5, ymn=5, ymx=9, nrows=4, ncols=4)
r3[] <- seq(0,1.5,0.1)
r_list <- list(r1,r2,r3)
# create SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(1,2,2),c(1,2,1)))
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1"), Polygons(list(Sr2), "s2")), 1:2)
dat = data.frame(ID = c("s1", "s2"), value = c("a", "b"))
row.names(dat) <- c("s1", "s2")
p <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpP, data = dat, 
                              match.ID = TRUE)

# check if rasters include the polygon
for (i in 1:length(r_list)) {

  inter1 <- raster::intersect(extent(r_list[[i]]), extent(p))
  print(paste0("p intersects r", i, ": raster::intersect ", isTRUE(inter1)) )
  inter2 <- gIntersects(as(extent(r_list[[i]]), 'SpatialPolygons'), p)
  print(paste0("p intersects r", i, ": rgeos::gIntersects ", inter2) )

}
```

Why does `raster::intersect` not recognize that the polygon covers part of `r1` (and `r3`), but `gIntersects` does it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get these results

```
raster::intersect(extent(r1), extent(p))
#class      : Extent 
#xmin       : 1 
#xmax       : 4 
#ymin       : 1 
#ymax       : 5 
gIntersects(as(extent(r1), 'SpatialPolygons'), p)
#[1] TRUE

raster::intersect(extent(r2), extent(p))
#NULL
gIntersects(as(extent(r2), 'SpatialPolygons'), p)
#[1] FALSE

raster::intersect(extent(r3), extent(p))
#NULL
gIntersects(as(extent(r3), 'SpatialPolygons'), p)
#[1] TRUE
```

So only with `r3` there is a difference. This is because you can argue whether there is an intersection or not as the polygons only touch each other. You can see that `gIntersection` returns a single SpatialPoint

```
gIntersection(as(extent(r3), 'SpatialPolygons'), p)
#class       : SpatialPoints 
#features    : 1 
#extent      : 4, 4, 5, 5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs         : NA
```

For `raster`, an intersection between polygons has to be a polygon as well, so no intersection here.